# preventing linux user from chmod 777

Tags: permissions, security, chmod

With `/etc/login.defs` having `UMASK 007` or `UMASK 027` for example will result in created files not having world `rwx` permissions.  But a user can `chmod 777` file they own correct?  Also for home accounts, typically under `/home`, a user can at any time do `chmod 777 ~` correct?  Which would give their home account world write and execute permissions, and would be bad.

*assuming good security practice is to not have home accounts `drwxrwxrwx`*

As an admin how can a `chmod 777` on certain files/folders be prevented?

To do so in any Linux, but I am most interested in **RHEL 8.7** and **RHEL 9.x**

Comment: Why would it be bad? What if user consciously wants for everybody to be able to access his files? That is their decision, and that is their data.

Comment: https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_7/2017-07-08/finding/V-72047

Comment: *security* says its bad, for various reasons, none of which I care to debate.  Simply put, if a user at any time can `chmod 777` and cause a security violation, well... somebody didn't think this logic thru and come up with corresponding security rule of *admins must prevent users from doing unauthorized chmod 777 on unauthorized folders without prior authorization*

Comment: I think a Linux Kernel Module which intercepts the syscall for `chmod` could achieve what you want. I would like to try it but I do know much about writing LKMs.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Wouldn't it be more appropriate for the user to access a shared directory than for the user to share their home.

Comment: @ron that rule is rather poorly written. The first part of the description is important: “If a world-writable directory has the sticky bit set”; the fix only makes sense in that context.

Comment: @ron well, I might ask the author of that message the same thing: **why**? That's the *user's* data, why the hell I am in the power to forbid them to control the data at their disposal as they like it? The users certainly may have the need to make a world-writeable directory (for the drop files they are wishing to process, for example). There are no *real* arguments why it is bad yet, only "it is bad because it is", and you ask a question and you don't even care why is your proposition wrong at the core.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon interception and can be done with pretty simple BPF program I think.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov oh, nice! I've read about eBPF but certainly I have not applied anything with BPF since I don't understand how that works. Do you have any resource (courses, videos, books or some useful site) about the use of `eBPF` in general? It should be useful for me learning about that.

Answer (score 0):

File permissions are usually up to the file owner to decide, I haven't heard of any existing implementation that would change that. (I think it's called "discretionary" access control for a reason.) There probably exist building blocks for that though, any sort of system call filter might do.

The real solution would likely be something like SELinux that provides security tags that regular users can't change.

But if you like, you might be able to could conjure something up with the regular file permissions... Consider a structure like below, where the group "john" has only the user "john" as its only member.

```
directory         user    group   perms
/home             root    root    0755
/home/john        root    john    0750
/home/john/john   john    john    0777   home directory of john
```

Here, john's home directory is at `/home/john/john` but whatever permissions it has, only john can access `/home/john` and hence `/home/john/john` (along with root, of course). John doesn't own `/home/john`, so they can't relax the permissions set there.

Comment: While this might solve the problem, it just looks horrible.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov, yes, that's something one would only do if they _really want to_. You could hide the ugly with symlinks, e.g. make the actual path in `$HOME` be `/home/john` and make that a symlink to where ever you put those nested directories. But yeah, something like SELinux would likely be the more proper solution.